# JSON decoder error using python json module

Tags: python, json, sdn

I have this simple son data structure:

```
{
  "hostname": "CORESW01",
  "vendor": "Cisco",
  "isAlive": True,
  "uptime": 123456,
  "users": {
    "admin": 15,
    "storage": 10,
  },
  "vlans": [
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN30",
      "vlan_id": 30
    },
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN20",
      "vlan_id": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Which I'm attempting to parse using the following code:

```
import json

with open("json-example.json") as f:
    data = f.read()
json_dict = json.loads(data)

print("Now printing each item in this document and the type it contains")



for k, v in json_dict.items():
    print("-- The key {0} contains a {1} value.".format(str(k), str(type(v))))
```

when the code is executed I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example-json.py", line 11, in <module>
    json_dict = json.loads(data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 4 column 14 (char 62)
```

Can someone help me diagnose this failure. I tried using the pub to step through the code and the reason goes the exception is not clear to me.

Comment: did you read the error message? It tells you exactly where is the issue (it doesn't tell exactly what is the issue but once you know where it is it's not hard to find out)

Comment: Your json is invalid. Frist thing is probably your main question but second is additional comma.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The boolean literals in JSON are lowercase `true` and `false`, but you are using the Python uppercase literals:

```
...
"isAlive": True,
...
```

Use the proper lowercase spelling instead:

```
...
"isAlive": true,
...
```

There is also a trailing comma in one of your objects:

```
...
"users": {
  "admin": 15,
  "storage": 10,
},
....
```

JSON does not allow trailing commas, you have to remove it:

```
...
"users": {
  "admin": 15,
  "storage": 10
},
....
```

---

Your full JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "hostname": "CORESW01",
  "vendor": "Cisco",
  "isAlive": true,
  "uptime": 123456,
  "users": {
    "admin": 15,
    "storage": 10
  },
  "vlans": [
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN30",
      "vlan_id": 30
    },
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN20",
      "vlan_id": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

This can be loaded without error:

```
json.loads('''{
  "hostname": "CORESW01",
  "vendor": "Cisco",
  "isAlive": true,
  "uptime": 123456,
  "users": {
    "admin": 15,
    "storage": 10
  },
  "vlans": [
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN30",
      "vlan_id": 30
    },
    {
      "vlan_name": "VLAN20",
      "vlan_id": 20
    }
  ]
}''')
# {'hostname': 'CORESW01', 'vendor': 'Cisco', 'isAlive': True, 'uptime': 123456, 'users': {'admin': 15, 'storage': 10}, 'vlans': [{'vlan_name': 'VLAN30', 'vlan_id': 30}, {'vlan_name': 'VLAN20', 'vlan_id': 20}]}
```

Comment: no I get this exception: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 9 column 3 (char 139)

Comment: @dcrearer Additional comma.